# How to download blockchain transaction data?

Tags: blockchain

I wish to download every transaction that happened on blockchain since the genesis. In particular, I want to download data for [BSC](https://www.binance.org/en/smartChain).

- How do I download blockchain data?, e.g. Is there an API or a protocol I can use?
- Once I've dowloaded the data to date... How do I subscribe to new transactions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run a full node (or connect to an external provider that runs a full node, but most of them have some rate limits and some don't allow subscriptions) and then query the [JSON-RPC](https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/rpc.html) API.

A widely used wrapper for the JSON-RPC API calls is [web3js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/). You can use their `web3.eth` library because of the compatilibity between Ethereum and BSC.

If you want to download all transactions, you'll need to loop through all blocks from 1 to `latest` using the [getBlock()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth.html#getblock) method, which also returns all transactions in this particular block.

For subscribing to new transactions, you'll subscribe to the [newBlockHeaders](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-subscribe.html#subscribe-newblockheaders) event, from which you can get the block number and query the block (see previous paragraph).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BlockchainSpider](https://github.com/wuzhy1ng/BlockchainSpider) to collect the data in the blockchain **without a full node**.
In particular, Blockchainspider also supports collecting the data on BSC.
Run this command for collecting the metadata, external transactions, and internal transactions of all blocks in BSC:

```
scrapy crawl blocks.bsc -a types=external,internal
```

In addition, you can even use BlockchainSpider to collect **label data** on the blockchain and deeply **mine the transaction network of a specific address**.

Enjoy it.